# Pass a Pre-made Array as an Arguement/Parameter in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods, variadic-functions, splat

I want to pass a list of my players in a Go Fish Card Game to a method that deals cards to players.  I want to pass in the already-made players array as an argument/parameter to the deal method.

I know I'd have to use the splat operator to pass in a *variable amount of arguments*, but how do I pass in a *pre-made array* of *varying elements?*

`def deal_to_players` is the function I'm revising.  I want to pass the `@player` array into deal_to_players `number_of_players` .

Thanks!  The code:

```
require_relative 'FishDeck.rb'
require_relative 'FishHand.rb'
require_relative 'FishPlayers.rb'


class FishGame

    attr_accessor :player
    attr_accessor :top_card_container, :next_turn   #next turn stores who's turn it is next
                                                    #How will I use that with the server?

    def initialize(number_of_fish_players)  
        @player = []
        i = 0   ##Revise so i can be 0?
        number_of_fish_players.times do #like 5.times do
        #puts "iteration i is: #{i}"    
            @player[i] = FishPlayer.new #Revise to PLAYER CLASS
            i += 1
        end
        #puts "PLAYER ARRAY: #{@player}"
        #puts "players 0: #{@player[0].player_hand.player_cards}, players 1: #{@player[1]}"
    end

    def deal_to_players(deck_name, number_of_players)   #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Need to pass the @player array to nuber_of_players so I can perform .each on it 5 times

        5.times do
            top_card = deck_name.pop_top_card
            @player1.player_cards << top_card

            top_card = deck_name.pop_top_card
            @player2.player_cards << top_card

            top_card = deck_name.pop_top_card
            @player3.player_cards << top_card

            top_card = deck_name.pop_top_card
            @player4.player_cards << top_card

            top_card = deck_name.pop_top_card
            @player5.player_cards << top_card
        end
    end

    def deck_to_player(game_deck, player_to)

        player_to.player_cards << top_card_container = game_deck.pop_top_card
        #Pops top deck card and shovels onto player_to 's cards
        player_to.looks_for_books
    end


    def player_to_player(game_deck, wanted_card, player_asked, player_asking)   #player_asking wants "wanted_card" from player_asked

        card_holder = player_asked.return_cards_requested(wanted_card)  #player in game's return card method and stores

        #puts "card holder[0] is: #{card_holder[0]}"
        #puts "wanted card is #{wanted_card}"


        if card_holder[0] == wanted_card    #element 0 will be the wanted_card or hold nothing

            player_asking.player_cards.concat(card_holder)
            card_holder.clear
            player_asking.looks_for_books
            @next_turn = "player_asking"
            #puts "next turn if player_asked has player_asking \'s wanted card"
        else

            card_from_deck = deck_to_player(game_deck, player_asking)

            if card_from_deck == wanted_card 
                @next_turn = "player_asking"
    #           puts "next turn if card from deck == card wanted: #{@next_turn}"
            else
                @next_turn = "NEXT PLAYER"
    #           puts "next turn if card from deck did NOT == card wanted: #{@next_turn}"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Why can't you just say `@player.each { ... }` inside `deal_to_players`?

Comment: Like what steen said?  Because it's an instance variable inside the class, I don't need to pass it?

Comment: Right, instance variables are attached to `self` so they're always available. You might want to rename it to `@players` while you're at it, it contains several things so using a plural name makes sense.

Comment: BTW, two spaces is a fairly standard Ruby indentation.  "Standard" isn't synonymous with "better," but it will make the code easier for most programmers to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
def deal_to_players(deck_name)   
  5.times do
  #Since @player is a instance variable (thanks to the @) you don't have to pass it:
  #It's in plain sight (inside the instance). note @player is a clumsy name for a collection
    @player.each do |pl|  #I'd prefer 'player' over 'pl', but now  it's confusing 
      pl.player_cards << deck_name.pop_top_card
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a method which accesses your @players instance variable

```
def deal_to_players(deck_name)
    5.times do
        number_of_players.times do |i|
            top_card = deck_name.pop_top_card
            @players[i].player_card << top_card
        end
    end
end


def number_of_players
    @players.count
end
```

Comment: That *would* be all well and dandy, and is actually quite a simple solution, but I am attempting to deal 1 card at a time to *each* player, like you would in a real card game.  First card to player 1, second card to player 2, etc.  
I'm not sure how I could reasonably implement that with this structure.

Comment: Alright, this should do what you need, assuming each player needs exactly 5 cards.